# ReflectionException in Route.php line 281: Function () does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 5 i'm Facing This Problem..
Here Is My Code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){

Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'user' => 'AuthController@login']);
Route::get('/handlelogin', ['as' => 'handlelogin', 'user' => 'AuthController@handlelogin']);
});
```

Comment: If you're using 5.2.27 and higher, remove web middleware.

Comment: FatalErrorException in ae8df401b51f2e82f0ff768d0c8b5c0050695036.php line 17:
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: That's a syntax error now inside one of your views.

Comment: Btw, chek inside `storage/framework/views/ae8df401b51f2e82f0ff768d0c8b5c0050695036.php` to see in which line of your view you have the error.

Comment: it is uses not user, it uses the controller and method.

Answer (score 1):

You have `'user' => 'AuthController@login` and `'user'=> 'AuthController@handlelogin'`

It should be `'uses' =>`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){

    Route::get('/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@login']);
    Route::get('/handlelogin', ['as' => 'handlelogin', 'uses' => 'AuthController@handlelogin']);
    });
```